# Error on C++: "error: int aaa::bbb is protected within this context"

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax-error, protected

After years of programming in C, I'm doing my first steps in C++.

I'm trying to grasp the "protected" concept, and there is a lot of material on the web that explains what a `protected` variable is, and what they are used for.  However, when trying to code a super-basic example, just to get my hands dirty with C++, I bumped into an error:

> error: 'int parent::protected1' is protected within this context

So, a little help will be appreciated.

```
class parent {
public:
    int getProtected() { return protected1; }
protected:
    int protected1;
};

class child: public parent { };

int main()
{
    child ch;

    cout << ch.protected1 << endl;    // error: 'int parent::protected1' is protected within this context
    cout << ch.getProtected() << endl;   // OK
    return 0;
}
```

Everywhere it is said that `protected` variables are only accessible within an inheritance hierarchy.  If that's the case, I'm trying to understand - what am I doing wrong here?

The concept of "protected variable" hasn't really sunk in. The `private` is well understood, as a private variable belongs to the child instance and therefore can be accessed only by child methods.  However, if a child can access a `protected` variable of the parent, does it mean a parent must be instantiated before a child can access this `protected` variable?

Comment: The way you are trying to use a `protected` variable here is equivalent to it being `private`. To access it like this it would need to be `public`.

Comment: Recommendation: Do not migrate from C to C++ without some good reference materials. The differences  in behaviour can be very jarring given how similar the languages usually are. The ideologies of the two languages are extremely different so even where the behaviour is the same, the best way to do something in C++ may be radically different. I have 3 years of truly crappy code I'm still finding and cleaning up from my transitional period  before I knuckled down with some good books and learned more than the syntax differences. The shorter you can keep your transition, the better off you'll be.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to access *directly* the class member `protected1`. This is possible only if the member is `public`.

Your class `child` can still access that member, so you could try:

```
class parent {
public:
    int getProtected() { return protected1; }
protected:
    int protected1;
};

class child: public parent { 
public:
  int getProtectedFromChild() { return protected1; }
};

int main()
{
    child ch;

    cout << ch.getProtected() << endl;   // OK
    cout << ch.getProtectedFromChild() << endl;   // This should work
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A protected member variable can only be accessed via *member functions* of the parent or child class, as your example shows.  Thus:

```
ch.protected1
```

does not compile since you are trying to access the data member from outside the class.

Answer (score 2):

> 1st question: Everywhere it is said that Protected variables are only accessible within an inheritance hierarchy. If that's the case, I'm trying to understand - what am I doing wrong here.

You're trying to access a protected member from `main` and `main` is outside the inheritance hierarchy. Just as `private` hides part of the implementation of a class from code outside that class, `protected` hides part of the implementation of a class from code outside that hierarchy. Since `main` is both outside the class and outside the hierarchy, both `protected` and `private` hide from it.

> 2nd question: The concept of "protected variable" hasn't really sunk in. The "private" is well understood, as a private variable belongs to the child instance and therefore can be accessed only by child methods. However, if a child can access a protected variable of the parent, does it mean a parent must be instantiated before a child can access this protected variable?

A parent must be instantiated before a child can even be instantiated. Children are instances of their parents.

If you have `class car : public vehicle`, then every `car` is also a `vehicle`. If you have an instance of the class `car`, you necessarily also have an instance of `vehicle`.

Comment: Note to those that follow: *Children are instances of their parents.* is staggeringly important. In c++ inheritance is an [Is-A relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). children *are* parents. Ralph, son of John, is John. Anywhere you can use a parent, you can use a child instead. If Dad can drive a car, Son can drive a car. Even if Son is a toddler. This can result in some bizarre code and bizarre bugs if you don't grasp this early. This is likely why base and derived are preferred to parent and child when discussing inheritance in programming.

Answer (score 2):

`protected` means that your class `child` has access to the `parent` (from which it publicly inherits) class' `protected1` field. If instead `protected` was `private`, `child` wouldn't be able to access this variable.

Your `main()` function isn't in a derivative class of `parent` - therefore it cannot access `protected` fields.